# Firebase module not found even if installed

Tags: reactjs, firebase

*At the first, anyone who will help me with this, thank you 1000000 multiplied by ∞.*

I just installed firebase using:
`npm install firebase`.
Then I imported firebase by:
`import firebase from 'firebase';`

I get an error saying:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' in 'C:\Abhirajshri\Coding
> Projects\web-templates\src'

I also tried by putting a slash:
`import firebase from '/firebase'`

Then a different error:

> Module not found: You attempted to import /firebase which falls
> outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of
> src/ are not supported.

And here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "web-templates",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
    "firebase": "^9.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help me...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is firebase v9.0. Should be like this:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
const config = { ... };

const app = initializeApp(config);
```

Check out the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdk-and-initialize).